# Django project pdfkit.from_url not render image

Tags: python, django, pdf

I have used PDFkit to render my HTML file into a PDF. However, the image is not being displayed. I tried the solution for a similar problem posted here and rewrote my code as so:

```
def get_pdf_for(request, slug):
    invoice = get_object_or_404(Invoice, slug=slug)
    data = dict()
    data["object"] = invoice
    data["DOB"] = "Jan 10, 2015"

    template = get_template('invoice/invoice_detail.html')
    html = template.render(data)
    pdf = pdfkit.from_string(html, False)

    filename = "sample_pdf.pdf"

    response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="' + filename + '"'
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

So check out your CSS and there might an issue there. This worked:

```
<div><img src="image.png"/></div>
```

And running command line in the directory with image.png:

wkhtmltopdf example.html example.pdf
But this does not:

```
<div><img src="image.png" style = "max-height: 100%; "/></div>
```

Because the image gets squished to 0 height. Firefox seems to correct this so it wasn't obvious.